# How to find node only in siblings using Xpath java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, nodes

I have stuck in finding a Xpath for xml which is having following structure....

```
<abc>
   <unique>
     <findme uniqueAtrr="itsme">Already Found Xpath For This</findme>
    </unique>
    <findme></findme>
    <findme></findme>
    <findme uniqueAtrr="itsme"> You Got Me</findme>   //NOTE : We don't know this position
    <findme></findme>   
</abc>
```

I got the XPath for Already Found using

```
/abc//unique/findme[@uniqueAtrr="itsme"]
```

So best way I believe to find is search for findme which is not there in unique tag...or find the node only in siblings...the one which I tried. ..

```
/abc//findme
```

This will give me the one which is inside the unique tag :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below xpath to match `"You Got Me"`:

```
/abc/unique/following-sibling::findme[@uniqueAtrr="itsme"]
```

Comment: seems like its not working why do we need /unique ??

Comment: Do you need to get this one `<findme uniqueAtrr="itsme"> You Got Me</findme>`, right?

Comment: ok. so why you think it might not work? `<unique>` is a sibling of `<findme uniqueAtrr="itsme"> You Got Me</findme>`. It should work. Just try it :)

Comment: WoooW I got it working...thing was I cant share the actual XML so it was dummy xml structure...with your logic I got it working thanks for saving my day :)